# Intersect, Union are failing on 10.1

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-10.1

After a huge help from Blah238.

I found exactly what is the problem.

I wasted few days checking our data, and trying many things.

The problem that I cannot do intersection between two polylines to give a result a new polyline.

It was working on 9.3. So I am not sure if it is not supposed to work , or why it is not working on 10.1

So, I modified the code to this.
Now this code is generating COM exception on my machine.

Blah can you please help if you can

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //ESRI License Initializer generated code.
        m_AOLicenseInitializer.InitializeApplication(new esriLicenseProductCode[] { esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeStandard, esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeAdvanced },
        new esriLicenseExtensionCode[] { });

        var geom1 = "LINESTRING (2 1, 7 1)".ToGeometry();
        var geom2 = "LINESTRING (3 1, 6 1)".ToGeometry();
        var targetOperator = (ITopologicalOperator)geom1;
        targetOperator.Simplify();

        IGeometry intersectGeometry = targetOperator.Intersect(geom2, geom2.Dimension);
        Console.WriteLine(overlapped1.ToWellKnownText());


        m_AOLicenseInitializer.ShutdownApplication();

    }

    static IGeometry GetOverlappedGeometry(IGeometry sourceGeometry, IGeometry targetGeometry, esriGeometryDimension dimension)
    {
        IGeometry overlappedGeometry = null;

        IGeometry localSourceGeometry;
        IGeometry localTargetGeometry;

        if (sourceGeometry.GeometryType > targetGeometry.GeometryType)
        {
            localSourceGeometry = targetGeometry;
            localTargetGeometry = sourceGeometry;
        }
        else
        {
            localSourceGeometry = sourceGeometry;
            localTargetGeometry = targetGeometry;
        }

        var targetOperator = (ITopologicalOperator)localTargetGeometry;

        if (targetOperator != null)
        {
            targetOperator.Simplify();

            IGeometry intersectGeometry = targetOperator.Intersect(localSourceGeometry, dimension);

            overlappedGeometry = intersectGeometry;
        }

        return overlappedGeometry;
    }
```

Please notice that the code is different that Blah code down , that I am using the dimension 1 is the intersection, and not dim0
Because I want a polyline
What the problem with 10.1?

Why I was able to do it on 9.3?

Comment: Can you post the source for the other referenced functions (`IsNullOrEmptyGeometry` and `IsGeometryIntersect`)? Also do you have any test data in WKT form that reproduces the error?

Comment: Also, do any/all/none of the geometries have SpatialReferences?

Comment: On your second invocation of `GetOverlappedGeometry` did you mean `GetOverlappedGeometry(geom3, overlapped1)` instead of `GetOverlappedGeometry(geom3, overlapped2)`?

Comment: yes, I meant GetOverlappedGeometry(geom3, overlapped1)

Comment: And regarding the other functions, they are irrelevant because they are not generating any errors. The error occur on the call of Intersection

Comment: Are you sure this code worked before? It doesn't seem to take into account the possibility that the intersection of two lines is 0-dimensional. What is the expected dimension of intersection in your second case?

Comment: BTW it doesn't crash on mine, it just just returns a 0 length polyline in my test case where I'm expecting a 0-dimensional intersection.

Comment: doesn't crash?
I have 10.1 SP1, and I am running it from the client (x86, or 32 bit).
I am wondering what is different on your machine.
It crashes on two machine, mine and the build server

Comment: I am also at 10.1 SP1. My machine and OS is 64-bit but I doubt that has anything to do with it. I've also tested with both .NET 4 and .NET 3.5 and both are fine for me. More likely is the data itself. If you want an apples-to-apples test, you need to provide some sample data that repros the crash, as well as the source to the "irrelevant" functions as they could have non-obvious side effects.

Comment: One thing I just thought of is that you are only simplifying one of the input geometries. You should probably set IsKnownSimple = false and then Simplify them both.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Apparently this is fixed at 10.2: [ITopologicalOperator::Intersect() fails with overlapping horizontal or vertical polylines in ArcGIS 10.1.](http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDgyNjY4)

If I modify your method signature to allow me to specify the expected dimension of intersection I get the expected output given my test cases (given in WKT below).

I adapted the WKT extension methods (GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/blah238/DnrGps_Wkt)) from the [DNRGPS source](http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/dnrgps/trunk/ArcMapIntegration/DNRGarmin_ArcMap/). [LINQPad 4](http://www.linqpad.net/) query Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/blah238/5054488).

```
using System;
using DnrGps_Wkt;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry;

namespace WKTTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.ActiveRuntime == null)
                ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.BindLicense(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.EngineOrDesktop);

            var geom1 = "LINESTRING (0 0, 2 2)".ToGeometry();
            var geom2 = "POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))".ToGeometry();
            var geom3 = "LINESTRING (0 1, 1 0)".ToGeometry();
            var overlapped1 = GetOverlappedGeometry(geom1, geom2, esriGeometryDimension.esriGeometry1Dimension);
            Console.WriteLine(overlapped1.ToWellKnownText());
            var overlapped2 = GetOverlappedGeometry(geom3, overlapped1, esriGeometryDimension.esriGeometry0Dimension);
            Console.WriteLine(overlapped2.ToWellKnownText());
        }

        static IGeometry GetOverlappedGeometry(IGeometry sourceGeometry, IGeometry targetGeometry, esriGeometryDimension dimension)
        {
            IGeometry overlappedGeometry = null;

            IGeometry localSourceGeometry;
            IGeometry localTargetGeometry;

            if (sourceGeometry.GeometryType > targetGeometry.GeometryType)
            {
                localSourceGeometry = targetGeometry;
                localTargetGeometry = sourceGeometry;
            }
            else
            {
                localSourceGeometry = sourceGeometry;
                localTargetGeometry = targetGeometry;
            }

            var targetOperator = (ITopologicalOperator)localTargetGeometry;

            if (targetOperator != null)
            {
                targetOperator.Simplify();

                IGeometry intersectGeometry = targetOperator.Intersect(localSourceGeometry, dimension);

                overlappedGeometry = intersectGeometry;
            }

            return overlappedGeometry;
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
LINESTRING (0 0,1.00000190734863 1.00000190734863)
MULTIPOINT (0.500001907348633 0.500001907348633)
```

Comment: Appreciate your help. I will try to find what is different.
As I told you the code is working on 9.3

Comment: Hi Blah...
I am not able to run your code, even it is very simple.

I am using the same library you used.
I will post my result.

Comment: Blah
I found the problem. The problem is I am doing intersection between 2 polylines to give result a new polyline, which in 10.1 I cannot do it.
I changed my question above.

Comment: I addressed that a while ago... you know that the intersection of two lines can be either a line OR a point, right? How can you be sure that the intersection of your two geometries is always going to be a line and not a point?

Comment: so, I don't understand your comment.
Does that mean the operation is invalid in 10.1 ?
I tested it on 9.3 and it is working.
So, what am I supposed to do?

Comment: I cannot test 9.3 so hopefully someone else who can can chime in. You could in the meantime go back through my previous comments and address some of the unanswered questions.

Comment: Sorry I missed that you updated the code. I get the same error as you.

Comment: See update, this is a known issue: [NIM082668 - ITopologicalOperator::Intersect() fails with overlapping horizontal or vertical polylines in ArcGIS 10.1.](http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDgyNjY4)

Comment: So, is it going to be fixed? because I don't think SP1 fixed it

Comment: 10.2 is what it says. Who knows when that will be out (and what other bugs it will introduce :)